# Filter nodes after receiving total number

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have the following query:

```
MATCH (n:Mob)
WITH count(n) as total, collect(n) as nodes
WITH nodes, total
UNWIND nodes as node
WHERE node.order > 8000 AND node.order < 8100
RETURN node, total
```

What I'm trying to do is to get to the total number of nodes (with label Mob) as a number then filter the actual returning nodes, so that I have a subset of the total nodes.

This currently gives me the error `Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I'`. Is there anyway to do what I want in one query, or does it need to be split into two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `WITH` clause between the `UNWIND` and `MATCH` clauses. This should work:

```
MATCH (n:Mob)
WITH COUNT(n) as total, COLLECT(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH total, node
WHERE 8000 < node.order < 8100
RETURN total, node
```

However, this is simpler if you are OK with getting a *single list* of suitable nodes instead of multiple return records:

```
MATCH (n:Mob)
RETURN
  COUNT(n) AS total,
  [m IN COLLECT(n) WHERE 8000 < m.order < 8100] AS nodes, COUNT(n) AS total
```

[UPDATE]

If you also want to do the equivalent of `SKIP` and `LIMIT` (assuming the SKIP and LIMIT counts are passed as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) `skip` and `limit`):

```
MATCH (n:Mob)
RETURN
  COUNT(n) AS total,
  [m IN COLLECT(n) WHERE 8000 < m.order < 8100][$skip..($skip+$limit)] AS nodes
```

Comment: Ah, your second query suits what I was looking for much better, since it makes much better sense as a format for pagination. I wish I could give you another +1 for thinking about intent!

Comment: Is it possible to put a `SKIP LIMIT` into the queries somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to cybersam's answer. In order to SKIP/LIMIT a list you need to do [x..y] where x and y are numbers i.e.

```
MATCH (n:Mob)
RETURN [m IN COLLECT(n) WHERE 8000 < m.order < 8100][0..10] AS nodes, COUNT(n) AS total
```

Or

```
MATCH (n:Mob)
WITH COUNT(n) as total, COLLECT(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH total, node
WHERE node.order > 1000
WITH total, node
SKIP 10
LIMIT 5
WITH collect(node) as nodes, total
RETURN nodes, total
```